# How to replace and delete different underscore in a single name row

Tags: r, string, dplyr, row, double-underscore

Let's suppose I have this situation

```
data = data.frame('A' = c('A_A_', 'B_B_'))
```

A_A_ where I would like to remove the final and replace the central underscore. What can I do to save the following two steps?

```
data %>% 
  mutate(A = sub("_$","", A)) %>% 
  mutate(A = sub("_","->", A))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unwieldy `base::strsplit`

```
paste0(unlist(strsplit(data$A, split = '_'))
[1:length(unlist(strsplit(data$A, split = '_'))) %% 2 == 1],
'->',
unlist(strsplit(data$A, split = '_'))
[1:length(unlist(strsplit(data$A, split = '_'))) %% 2 == 0])
[1] "A->A" "B->B"
```

that likely wouldn't be called a 'one-liner'...

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sub()` with capture groups:

```r
data$A <- sub("([^_]+)_([^_]+)_", "\\1->\\2", data$A)
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

- `([^_]+)` match and capture in `\1` the first term
- `_` match the first underscore
- `([^_]+)` match and capture in `\2` the second term
- `_` match the final underscore

Then we splice together the two segments separated by `->`.

Comment: Always appreciate your step thru of the execution, and first time to see the 'splice' employed between the capture groups, but makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Chris Actually, there is probably an `strsplit()` way of doing this which avoids regex entirely.  You could post that as an answer.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  thank you so much. Actually I am not very familiar with regex so may could advice ito me some source where to learn. For example I do nor even know the meaning  of `([^_]+)`

Comment: `[^_]+` means _not_ underscore (any character except underscore), one or more times.

Comment: Thank you and how about the `\` mark?